# SQL Set transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

What happens if you don't use 'Begin Transaction' with an update query for example? Is it still saved in the transaction log?

Say you run the following, will it still be saved to the transaction log automatically? As you can see No 'begin transaction', commit, etc is used below.

```
UPDATE Customers
SET ContactName = 'Alfred Schmidt', City= 'Frankfurt'
WHERE CustomerID = 1;
```

I think I'm a little confused on transaction log vs transaction? I  think I though setting 'begin transaction' was mandatory for a transaction to be saved in the transaction log?

Thank you

Comment: It's not mandatory, SQL creates one anyway for you whether specified or not.

Comment: Each statement is implicitly committed using an [autocommitted transaction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878(v=sql.105).aspx) when you don't specify an explicit BEGIN TRAN (or have `IMPLICT_TRANSACTIONS ON`).

Answer (score 0):

> Although BEGIN TRANSACTION starts a local transaction, it is not
>   recorded in the transaction log until the application subsequently
>   performs an action that must be recorded in the log, such as executing
>   an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement. An application can perform
>   actions such as acquiring locks to protect the transaction isolation
>   level of SELECT statements, but nothing is recorded in the log until
>   the application performs a modification action.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929(v=sql.105).aspx